# Using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript with JQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog, code-behind, clientscript

I have the following method in aspx code behind which displays a jquery dialog. Is it possible for this method to return **true** if the user clicks "Submit" on the dialog?

```
    Sub DisplayDialog()
        Dim title As String = "title"
        Dim content As New StringBuilder()
        content.Append(@"<script type=text/javascript>
          $(function () {
           $('#dialog')
            .dialog({
            title: 'title',
            modal: 'true',
            buttons: {
                'Submit': function () { 
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this)
                        .dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>")
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), title, content.ToString())
    End Sub
```

### **EDIT:**

Here is a more complete picture of what I have:

```
Sub GridView1_onRowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Select Case e.CommandName
        Case "Upload"
            DisplayDialog()
            //Get result here from jquery dialog. Do something if result was true             
        Case "Something"
     End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you want to return true; instead you can call a javascript function.

Comment: The calling method (which I want to pass the true result to) does some file uploads if the user clicks submit. Are you suggesting I have the calling method be a web method so I can call it from another javascript method?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can have the webmethod written in codebehind which can be called by the jquery ajax function inside the "Submit" button click.

Comment: Please see my edit. For my understanding, is it not possible then to get the result from the jquery dialog back to the onRowCommand method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the return of the Modal Dialog in order to perform an action, this is the pattern you should follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var $dialog = $("#dialog");
        var $foo = $("input:submit[id$=foo]");
        var confirmed = false;

        $dialog.hide();

        $dialog.dialog({
            width: "300px",
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                OK: function (e) {
                    $dialog.dialog("close");
                    confirmed = true;
                    $foo.click();
                },
                Cancel: function (e) {
                    $dialog.dialog("close");
                    confirmed = false;
                }
            }
        });

        $foo.click(function (e) {
            if (!confirmed) {
                $dialog.dialog("open");
            }

            return confirmed;
        });
    });
</script>

    <div>
        <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" ID="foo" OnClick="foo_Click" />
    </div>
    <div id="dialog">
        <asp:Label Text="Are u sure u wanna do it?" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

Basically you use a flag to indicate what button was pressed, and you return that flag when clicking a button.

You could take this sample and adjust it to fit your specific needs

[This is the full working Example on my GitHub](https://github.com/jupaol/SO-Answers/blob/master/Visual%20Studio%202012/src/SO/WebForms/WebForms_1/Topics/JQuery/jQueryUI/ModalDialog.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion Jupaol. I am fairly new to this, so I was wondering is there any benefit in using the ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript in code-behind vs. writing the jquery in aspx?

Comment: That approach is used when you want to create JavaScript dynamically by the server in response to a postback. It is useful when you are creating your own custom AJAX reusable controls. I try to write simple JavaScript when possible using external js files or inline scripts because they are easier to maintain and to debug. I would recommend you to do the same, and only use dynamically script when the script itself needs to be dynamically created.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a question about your example. What is the difference between saying "var $dialog = $("#dialog");" as opposed to "var dialog = $("#dialog");" without the "$" infront of the variable name?

Comment: There's no difference at all. However I tend to use the `$` prefix in my variables when they represent a jQuery object. This technique has improved the readability of my code since it's really easy to spot when a variable represents a jQuery object. The `$` is a valid token when naming javascript objects. For example, in jQuery, the `$` represents just a variable named `$`

Comment: I see. I hadn't seen $ infront of the variable before so thought I'd ask. Thanks again!